# show "My billing information is the same as my shipping information." option when creating order from admin

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal version 9.3.14.
Option "My billing information is the same as my shipping information." gets available on checkout page automatically. But when creating order from Admin side this option is not available resulting into filling same address twice in shipping and billing address.

How can I make this option available on admin side also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's roughly supported but not a great experience. Essentially, you would have to create the order without any billing details then create a shipment for the order. After doing so, when you go back to the order edit screen and click the button to add a billing address, it will default to copying the address from the shipment.

Ideally, the shipment add form would have a similar option to copy from the billing address instead, since the order management flow is different from the checkout flow. I'm going to file that as a feature request for the Commerce Shipping module.

Comment: Yes, currently we are following the same steps. Creating an order without billing details, and then edit the order again and click that checkbox to copy the address. But it becomes little bit tedious when there many orders to process in a day.

Comment: I forgot to link to the ticket I created. I think this is fixable. : D https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping/issues/3316917